# How to prevent subdomains to be redirected to https

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I wanted to redirect the site to https:// but I don't want subdomains to be redirected. When I type: dev.mycreditstatus.co.za, it is redirected to https:// even if I don't want it to.

Here's the code in my .htaccess (public_ssl) currently:

```
ErrorDocument 404 https://mycreditstatus.co.za/404.php

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^imupost\.co\.za$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

.htaccess (public_html):

```
ErrorDocument 404 https://mycreditstatus.co.za/404.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(pp5fdr) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

What modifications shall I make to get this working? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `public_html` .htaccess, you have no condition which limits it to the main domain only (this assumes your subdomains are rooted in the same directory). You need another `RewriteCond` to match only the main domain:

```
ErrorDocument 404 https://mycreditstatus.co.za/404.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# Only redirect to https if the main domain (no subdomain) is matched
# case-insensitively in HTTP_HOST
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mycreditstatus\.co\.za$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(php05142013) [NC]
# added flags...
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. I'm new to regex and mod rewrite so I wasn't so sure what to put in .htaccess. Thanks again for helping me out.